# Commands for launching a replacement instance from an AMI in AWS using powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

Can you please let me know if there are any powershell commands to launch for launching a replacement instance from an AMI in AWS using powershell?

I tried searching the net and found this command "New-AWSWindowsHelpersReplacementInstance" but when I run this I get an error message:

New-AWSWindowsHelpersReplacementInstance : The term 'New-AWSWindowsHelpersReplacementInstance' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
At line:1 char:1

- New-AWSWindowsHelpersReplacementInstance -Region eu-west-2 -InstanceI ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-AWSWindowsHelpersReplacementInstance:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: Have you tried [loading](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AWSWindowsHelpers/1.2.33/Content/public%5CNew-AWSWindowsHelpersReplacementInstance.ps1) the function first?

Comment: Got the answer, I have to install Import-Module AWSWindowsHelpers to the command to work..
More Info - https://github.com/Sam-Martin/AWSWindowsHelpers/blob/master/readme.md